# Button border issue in LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-button

I have created button without any border using LWUIT resource editor. I am able to see that button with all my properties set. However, when i am trying to add an image into this button using its image constructor, i am able to see a thick border around my image. I tried changing the button into Label, still image is coming. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the button border type as `Empty` on ResourceEdit? If not, set the button border type as `Empty` for selected and unselected style on ResourceEdit. It should work.